how can I input RGB images into the LSTM network?
I want to input 300 RGB (224*224) photos into LSTM network. I am new and I don't know how to write input_shape.
I write input shape into the 224*224 an there is a error here
` `ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call().

  Invalid input shape for input Tensor("data:0", shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32). Expected          
  Arguments received by Sequential.call():
     • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
   • mask=None``


It's possible that the quiet is because such a question has been asked and answered many times on many sites... Research your problem first. To get a faster answer you need to then let us know what you've tried towards fixing it and how it's not working for you (is giving new errors?).
